# Are all the Giants dead from Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the seasons so far, we have only seen three giants, and now they are all dead. Will we see anymore in the future, especially since the great war with the White walkers hasn't occurred yet?

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126774/game-of-thrones-giants-where-are-their-cities?rq=1

Comment: "Will we see more giants in future?", we do not know. It's a speculative question which will lead to opinion based answers. We do not know how many giants are there in show canon. In books, there are plenty.

Comment: related/possible dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/in-the-got-book-and-or-hbo-canon-are-the-giants-now-below-a-minimum-viable-popu

Comment: I see this one of two ways, either the answer is, "Yes, all the giants are dead.", or "No, some giants are still alive". In the first case this runs into possible duplicate territory, in the second case it turns into speculation/future works.

Comment: If Brienne and Tormund hook up, their offspring would probably be of rather substantial proportions.

Comment: I'm wrong in dimly remembering something about the three or four giants we see at one point being described as the last ones? I thought that's what made each giant's death so tragic.

Answer (score 1):

This is open to speculation:

> Wun Wun was a Giant, possibly the only one to reside in Hardhome and **possibly the last giant to ever be seen on the show**

In the books, his fate is unknown too, but he is in confrontation with Stannis' knights:

> [Jon] hears a commotion at Hardin’s Tower. He rushes there and sees Wun Wun smashing the head of a knight named Ser Patrek of King’s Mountain... One foolish man shoots the giant in the back with a crossbow, and in retaliation Wun Wun grabs the man by the leg and whips him into the wall

This happens just before the close of the last published book.

Source: [gameofthrones.wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wun_Weg_Wun_Dar_Wun). Emphasis and editing is mine

Comment: What's the last episode you watched?

Comment: @kuhl - I don't watch them, I read the books. I'm guessing Wun Wun go splat?

Comment: Yeah.  Wun Wun has a Boromir moment in S6E9.  Obviously not sure if it happens in the books as well since we're not there yet, but at least in show canon he's dead.

Comment: @kuhl - fair enough. I'll have a look through the books when I get home tonight and modify the answer in line to that. But seeing as the question is tagged GoT (i.e. the TV show), then I'm not sure if a book answer would fit the OP's question.

Comment: It might, though it'd have to be in the 'we don't know in the show, but the books give other examples that may or may not be accurate to the show' type of answer.